# ruTorrent creates files that shouldn't download

Tags: bittorrent

Even files that have their priority set to "Don't download" seem to be created and fully allocated using `rutorrent 3.8` on a Debian box.

I believe this stems from a packet 'accidentally' being received and the files thus being created so as not to waste said packet.

How do I correct this behavior? Is there any way of setting up a script/plugin to automatically delete these files as soon as they're created?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the `~/.rtorrent.rc` file and change or insert the line:

```
system.file_allocate.set = no
```

This will prevent `rtorrent` from fully allocating files during download.